# VS Code The system cannot find the module due to space in file path

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I'm new to VS Code, and trying to run a project and review the scene but keep getting thrown an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\XXXX'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:871:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

After reviewing the code, I believe it's an issue related to the spaces in the file path (i.e. XXXX YYY ZZZ), but due to work/school server issue, changing the folder or path name is not a feasible option - is there a quick fix to this error so I can run the project?

```
Node command path: "c:\Users\XXXX YYY ZZZ\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\[cmd file]"
Node bin path: "c:\Users\XXXX YYY ZZZ\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\[node file]
Workspace: "c:\Users\XXXX YYY ZZZ\[folder]"
```

Need to be able to run the project.

Comment: All Windows files and directories with spaces in them have an alternate filename that is safe.  You could use that instead.  `dir /x` will show the short names.  Obviously, you can't use this for portable code that runs other places, but you could use it to patch your code to make it work in your specific computer.  But, there's probably a simpler way to solve this issue, but you don't really show us any of the details about where the problem is coming from.  You don't show the command line you're using to launch it.  You don't show any code.

Comment: FYI, if the problem is caused by the top level module you're trying to load from the command line, then you can put double quotes around the filename on the command line such as `node "my module.js"` and that will tell Windows that the whole thing is the filename, including the spoaces.

Comment: "_I believe it's an issue related to the spaces in the file path_" - so there are no issues when the space is removed? Or are you just guessing?